# Add a caption under an image

Tags: captions

I'm trying to get "Figure 1" as a caption under my picture but it isn't displaying for some reason, can somebody spot my error?

I've removed text/formulas that wouldnt affect this part of the code, and included the packages that Im using...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,hyperref,parskip}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.6 cm}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{The Model}

\graphicspath{ {graph/} }
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{graph}
\caption{A possible graph for the concentration of a drug in function of time}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why yes! You need a complete document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` for it to compile. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: In isolation there is no reason to expect this to fail, so a fuller example will be needed. (Probably) not relevant to the matter in hand, but `\graphicspath{ {graph/} }` should usually be in preamble not in an individual float.

Comment: its not the full code, I have got \begin{document} etc... and even as a preamble this doesnt work...

Comment: @bearrrr Werner was trying to say that you should add your full code and not just a code snippet because maybe the problem is not in the code snippet.

Comment: updated, sorry didnt realise Weners point

Comment: Does that exact example not produce a caption when you compile it? Because the code looks OK.

Comment: It doesnt even display my graph, and when I just use:     \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{graph} without the \begin/end{figure} it displays (but without the caption) it's so annoying! :/

Comment: `\graphicspath{ {graph/} }` should be in the preamble, not inside the document environment.

Comment: I get the caption above the image, because you specified `capposition=top`

Comment: Your code works fine. The spacing needs some tweaking, but it works.

Comment: 0.75 was too big for my graph with the caption... ahah, omg such a simple error...thanks anyways guys also, Ive added [h] so its not at the top...thanks again

Comment: @bearrrr: Instead of using some `scale` value to "make it fit within the text block horizontally" (say), use `width=\textwidth`. Then you will be guaranteed that the width (horizontally) will be `\textwidth`...